# Exception at Word opening with M2Doc

Tags: m2doc

I've been using M2Doc on multiple Word documents with no problem.
But I have one template that creates an exception when opening from Eclipse. It comes from an older version of Word (I have however saved it as docx with a recent).

There is also a problem when opening from Word outside Eclipse.

[screen copy of the error 1 I get when opening in Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7Uy.png)

[screen copy of the error 2 I get when opening in Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfph4.png)

I just tried with a simple {m:self.name} and it looks like after ignoring these errors in Word outside Eclipse, the expression is actually correctly evaluated. But when I display the field codes in this generated Word document, I still see see the M2Doc expression: {m:self.name}FCP. Usually these field code disappear from the generated document.

Any idea?
Thank you very much

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation.<init>(OleAutomation.java:128)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editorsupport.win32.OleEditor.handleWord(OleEditor.java:333)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editorsupport.win32.OleEditor.oleActivate(OleEditor.java:554)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editorsupport.win32.OleEditor.createPartControl(OleEditor.java:187)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:154)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:361)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:964)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1000)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:660)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:107)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4735)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:658)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:622)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:790)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:404)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1266)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3195)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3100)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3068)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3059)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:569)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:524)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenFileAction.openFile(OpenFileAction.java:103)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenSystemEditorAction.run(OpenSystemEditorAction.java:96)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:215)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$1.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:183)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:802)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1118)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:454)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:310)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4213)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4030)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3630)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1158)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1047)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
at org.polarsys.capella.core.platform.sirius.ui.app.CapellaApplication.start(CapellaApplication.java:117)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. If you have a reproduction case on the last version of M2Doc, you can open an issue [here](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/issues).